# GUI app to create maps made up of polygons

Tags: gui, drawing, vector-graphics

What could I use for creating maps with polygon-shaped sections? Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image: example]

This software should be able to create and edit these polygon maps.

Ideally, they could be exported in a convenient format, such as SVG, but all I need is that I can drag the points of the polygons around and add new polygons/points.

Software for any common platform/OS will do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/)? It's free and seems to meet your requirements:

[image: Inkscape Example Document UI]

- You cannot have anchored vertices, where one vertice of the first polygon automatically follows another vertice of the second polygon on translation
- However, the vertices can be exactly aligned by each other with the snapping tools (see selected switches on the east toolbar)
- You can select, add, delete, move vertices (see selected tool on the west toolbar)
- Removing vertices can lead to a curve, which can be fixed (see the lower north toolbar)
- The file can be saved as SVG